# magento still trying to load compiled files even after disabled

Tags: magento-1.7

Anyone help with this, it's very wierd and I've run out of ideas.

I've manually disabled compiler by commenting out the 2 lines in includes/config.php, I've also deleted the includes/src and includes/stat directories to be complete but when I try to edit a product I get errors because magento is trying to include files in the compiled includes/src folder (which no longer exists)

I've also tried recompiling and accessing on the compiled site when I get another error.

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php' (include_path='/content/includes/src:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /content/includes/src/Uni_Fileuploader_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Grid.php on line 9
```

I'm figuring to sort the site so I can at least edit with the compiler disabled and then work through issues with compiled site but currently can't do either as magento seems to want to access compiled files even when compiler disabled.

running 1.7.0.2

Additionally - this may or may not be related.

When I run compiler.php from command line I get a bunch of warnings as follows but the compilation processes still seem to work.

```
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Mage/Core/Model/App.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Varien/Event/Collection.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Varien/Event/Observer/Collection.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Mage/Core/Model/Config.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Mage/Core/Model/Config/Base.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Varien/Simplexml/Config.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Varien/Object.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Varien/Profiler.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Zend/Log.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Mage/Core/Model/Store/Exception.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Mage/Core/Exception.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Zend/Log/Formatter/Simple.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Zend/Log/Formatter/Interface.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Zend/Log/Writer/Stream.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Zend/Log/Writer/Abstract.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
PHP Warning:  include(): realpath failed to canonicalize Zend/Log/FactoryInterface.php - bailing in /content/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the second part of your question: are you using APC by any chance?

In this case [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59493) may be relevant to you. To cut it short, edit your APC config, on Debian-based system in `/etc/php5/conf.d/20-apc.ini` and set:

```
apc.stat=1
```

Remember to clean APC and your magento cache and then try to run the compiler again.

Comment: This worked out well for second part of question, thanks. Still same issue with first part of question when compiler enabled but at least can edit products when uncompiled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to turn off `apc.stat=1` because this function speeds up your installation. I have a fix, but it's not the greatest fix, because you need to change code in the core.

Go to the file "lib/Varien/Autoload.php" and scroll to line 93.

**Change**

```
return include $classFile;
```

**With (not the most beautiful fix)**

```
if (file_exists(realpath(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))).'/app/code/core/'.$classFile) or
    file_exists(realpath(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))).'/app/code/community/'.$classFile) or
    file_exists(realpath(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))).'/app/code/local/'.$classFile) or
    file_exists(realpath(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))).'/lib/'.$classFile)) {
        return require_once $classFile;
    } else {
        return include $classFile;
    }
```

The reason i'm using the `file_exists` function is simple. The function `include()` gives an error if the included file doesn't exist and the script keeps running. The function `require()` gives also an error but **stops** running the script. With this fix Magento keeps running likes it always runs, but without the APC-cache error and if a included file doesn't exist your Magento installation keeps running and doesn't stop rendering.

You can also downgrade your APC extension. In the version 3.1.9 (last stable version) you don't get this error.

Comment: Or you could just flush APC's cache so it sees the new files, instead of hacking around like this.

Comment: You think that will solve the problem? Please test it before you say something. Think and you know that if you want to see the changes, you must flush the APC-cache. The only way to solve this issue is to use the absolute path.

Comment: Ok well by setting stat=0 you told APC not to check if the file has been modified, and continue to use the old file. Any "trick" to make your changes take affect won't be reliable.

Comment: You can use the normal apc.php file to flush the cache. http://git.php.net/?p=pecl/caching/apc.git;a=blob_plain;f=apc.php;hb=HEAD